# IO monad arguments usage without IO

Tags: haskell

I am having this issue the function calculate accepts IO a type and I already have a function
that return the same thing but it accepts a as her type. Below is my code. I have been searching around the web for some time but i couldn't manage to fix my error.Tahnks in advance for your help.

```
pureCalculate :: Expr (Double -> Double -> Double) -> Map.Map String Double -> Double

calculate :: IO(Expr (Double -> Double -> Double)) -> Map.Map String Double -> IO Double

calculate expr args =
    do let x = pureCalculate expr args
       return x
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like

```
calculate ioexpr args = do
    expr <- ioexpr
    return $ pureCalculate expr args
```

In order to use a value wrapped in the `IO` monad, you first have to extract it using `<-` notation, or you can use other functions like `fmap` to map a function to the contents.

If you wanted to use `fmap` in this case, you could do something like

```
calculate ioexpr args = fmap (\expr -> pureCalculate expr args) ioexpr
```

Which is equivalent to

```
calculate ioexpr args = fmap (`pureCalculate` args) ioexpr
```

or

```
calculate ioexpr args = fmap (flip pureCalculate args) ioexpr
```